# Javascript dynamic array alternative

Tags: javascript, reactjs, performance

I'v created a masonry grid with Flexbox. The order of the items was vertically, therefore I created a function to sort the items horizontally:

Before:

```
1 4 7
2 5 8
3 6 9
```

After (with my function):

```
1 2 3
4 5 6
7 8 9
```

Function to sort the items:

```
// Function to order the post items for the masonry Grid
// @param {Array} Posts
// @param {Integer} Number of columns
// @return {Array} Ordered list of posts
export const orderItems = (postItems, columns) => {
  let posts = [];
  let orderedPosts = [];

  for (let col = 0; col < columns; col++) {
    posts[col] = [];
  }

  let col = 0;
  for (let i = 0; i < postItems.length; i++) {
    if (i % columns === 0) {
      posts[col].push(postItems[i]);
    } else if (i % columns === 1) {
      posts[col + 1].push(postItems[i]);
    } else if (i % columns === 2) {
      posts[col + 2].push(postItems[i]);
    } else if (i % columns === 3) {
      posts[col + 3].push(postItems[i]);
    } else if (i % columns === 4) {
      posts[col + 4].push(postItems[i]);
    } else if (i % columns === 5) {
      posts[col + 5].push(postItems[i]);
    } else if (i % columns === 6) {
      posts[col + 6].push(postItems[i]);
    }
  }

  for (let col = 0; col < columns; col++) {
    for (let post = 0; post < posts[col].length; post++) {
      orderedPosts.push(posts[col][post]);
    }
  }

  return orderedPosts;
};
```

I used a dynamic array because It depends on the screen size how many columns exist. But I'm not very happy with my solution..
Is there a better way (better performance) to solve my problem (without dynamic array)?

Thanks for your help !

Comment: this likely belongs on codereview, that said, simplification should not be harder than  `posts[col + (i % columns)].push(postItems[i]);` or use a filter/map

Comment: All those `if`s are pointless. Just do `posts[col + (i % columns)].push(postItems[i % columns])`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest would be to use Flexbox own property, `order`, and e.g. when 3 in each column, give element an inline style of:

- 1,4,7 `order: 1`
- 2,5,8 `order: 2`
- 3,6,9 `order: 3`

Then, e.g. in below sample, you set the item's `order` and parent `height` inline with your script.

```css
.parent {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column wrap;
  align-content: flex-start;      
}


/*  for this demo only  */
.parent {
  counter-reset: num;
}
.parent div::before {
  counter-increment: num;
  content: counter(num);
}
.parent div {
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
  margin: 5px;
  background: #ccc;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent" style="height: 270px;">
  <div style="order: 1;"></div>
  <div style="order: 2;"></div>
  <div style="order: 3;"></div>
  <div style="order: 1;"></div>
  <div style="order: 2;"></div>
  <div style="order: 3;"></div>
  <div style="order: 1;"></div>
  <div style="order: 2;"></div>
  <div style="order: 3;"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: I have to use direction column for the masonry grid.

Comment: @JonasNiedermair Updated my answer with a sample

Comment: looks great .. but can I make this also more dynamical? Because I don't know how many columns there will be (depends on the width of the container).. and I have also a button to load more items then 9

Comment: @JonasNiedermair Based on the fact that the items width and height is known, you can use a media query to change the `.parents` height, so it matches the amount of columns.

Comment: I do this already.. I've a function to calculate how many  columns my grid have (depends on the container width)  and a function to calculate the containers height. But when I have for example: 18 posts, then I have to write for every item this: .parent div:nth-child(x) ?? Is there no way to make it more dynamical? Because with your solution only the first 9 posts have the correct order

Comment: @JonasNiedermair You set/update the `order` inline. Updated my answer to make that more clear.

Answer (score 2):

Use array.map:

```js
var before = [
    [1, 4, 7],
    [2, 5, 8],
    [3, 6, 9]
];

var after = before[0].map((e, i) => before.map(row => row[i]));

console.log(after);
```